# The identity iPhone developer doesnt match any valid,non-expired certificate

Tags: ios, ipad, certificate, bundle, provisioning

I am getting the aforementioned  error when i try to build for an iPad.Also there is another error. I have my personal mac and the office mac.When i tried to do the project i started doing it on my Personal machine. So my code runs smoothly, builds for an iPad. I can see the app running on the ipad. So i had created a developer provisional certificate and did the testing on the ipad for the above scenario. 
 Now 2 days later i created a distribution certificate as well.
 I copied my project from my personal mac to office mac and connected the same ipad. So i now go into Xcode->Organizer->Provisioning profiles and see under status "Valid signing identity not found". When i first connected it had only a provisional certificate with that status.I refreshed the provisioning profiles and it asked for my credentials. I did that. It then adds  the distribution profile i created this morning to the list. This also has the status as "valid signing identity not found".Then i get this error message "No value was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'. I am new to app development.This is infact my very first app. Also while building the project for iPad i get the error as mentioned in the title. I changed in the .plist file the "Bundle identifier" to match exactly as it said on my project. No typo issues, i cross-checked. In the same .plist file what are the "Bundle display Name", "Executable Name" and "Bundle Name" to be set?Right now i see them on both my macs as ${product..} etc..I have to see to it that, I can load the app on to ipad from my office machine and personal machine..Do i have to get two certificates, download them, install them for 2 different machines?It would be great if some one can explain it in detail. Thanks..

Comment: @Sheena. I was trying to explain the scenario clearly. Some people say there is not enough information. So i went ahead and gave you the entire story. But if you like it breaked down then in a gist 1)the error in title while building 2)Valid signing identity not found 3)No value was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'. These are the 3 errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to copy an iOS project to a 2nd Mac without changing the provisioning, you will also need to copy all your Certificates with their private keys from your Keychain on the first Mac, then either copy or re-download any provisioning profiles using the same developer account you used on the first Mac.  Re-downloading the Developer/Distribution Certificates to a 2nd Mac will generally not work, since the private keys will be missing.  So you have to copy them from the originating Mac.

Comment: @hotpaw2.Thanks for your reply. I can download the certificates from developer member center. But what about the keychains. I can see 4 things in my keychain access.2 public(1 developer,1 distribution),2 private (1 developer, 1 distribution). So can i just copy them/email them? Like i said new to app development and mac OS as well.

Comment: Re-downloaded certificates on a 2nd Mac are useless and likely confusing.  Best to remove these copies from the Keychain of the 2nd Mac.  Read the Keychain docs on .p12 export, and then get the certificates from the originating Mac.